# Implementing S3 Generic/Methods in C

Tags: r, dispatch

I've been looking to implement some code I originally wrote in R into C for performance improvements.  Things have been going swimmingly so far, but one item that I'm struggling with is how to implement S3 Generic / Methods in C while minimizing overhead.

The use case for my function would most of the time go directly to the default method which I figure I can implement within the generic, or worst case have one level of S3 dispatch in C to the default.  That said, I want to allow the possibility of non-trivial dispatch to occur.

I've found a few references to `DispatchOrEval`, but it seems this function is reserved for internal use due to the `attribute_hidden` declaration in `src/eval.c` ahead of the function definition:

```
attribute_hidden
int DispatchOrEval(SEXP call, SEXP op, const char *generic, SEXP args,
           SEXP rho, SEXP *ans, int dropmissing, int argsevald)
{
```

Is there any other way to achieve S3 dispatch from C directly with limited overhead?

For reference, I've been reading the following:

- A **[blog post](http://biostatmatt.com/archives/280)** discussing `attribute_hidden`
- Hadley's **[Advanced R book referencing](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html#c-find-source)** `DispatchOrEval`
- Writing R Extensions
- `src/eval.c` and others

I'll admit a lot of it is still pretty new to me, so my understanding so far could be completely wrong.

---

EDIT: to address Martin's request of a specific example, I'm trying to write a function `checkArgs` (or some such) that when used like so:

```
FUN <- function(x, y, z) {
   checkArgs(x=...,y=..., z=...)
   # More code here
}
```

would provide a simple way to quickly check that the arguments are what I want them to be.

For example, something like:

```
FUN <- function(x, y, z) {
   checkArgs(x=matrix(numeric(), ncol=3),y=..., z=...)
   # More code here
}
```

Would check that Argument `x` is a three column numeric matrix.  The function I want to allow dispatch on is the function that compares `x` to the template specification in `checkArgs` (not shown here, but will likely be called **[`alike`](https://github.com/brodieG/alike)** to compare alikeness of objects).  Most of the time, it would use the default C version, but if a user creates a method for that generic and validates with an object of that method's class, then the provided method would be used instead.

In order for this to be generally useful, including use in SPLIT-APPLY-COMBINE analysis, `checkArgs` must run very quickly.  Because of that I started re-writing the comparison function in `C`, but in so doing, lost the dispatch capability that I would like to retain, even though the most common use case is to rely on the default method.

Comment: Why are you attempting to do this? Are you _certain_ your bottleneck is S3 dispatch?

Comment: I don't know of any way to do S3 dispatch without calling an R function. As Josh said, are you sure S3 is slowing you down? The cost of S3 dispatch is on the order of 1-2 microseconds. Finally, there have been some recent commits to the R source that speed up S3 dispatch, and they will should show up in the next release.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich, yes, I'm certain.  My function currently evaluates in 1.5 microseconds in C (including initial invocation from R), and would add 2 microseconds per S3 dispatch, of which there could be several.  The function is intended to be as optimized as possible so that it could conceivably be added to R functions that are run millions of times as part of Split-Apply-Combine type analysis without overly compromising overall execution time.

Comment: @wch, thanks for the heads up about the forthcoming S3 improvements.  By "I don't know how to do S3 dispatch without calling an R function", you mean "there is no way to get access to the internal R method of doing so from C"?

Comment: It would be great to see an explicit (simplified) example; since S3 dispatch is already in C, it's not clear what could be gained by invoking it (via a C-level formulation of an R function call, as I think @wch has in mind) yourself from C. But maybe there are other solutions, like  memoizing and our old friend vectorization perhaps _prior_ to splitting, that would help.

Comment: @MartinMorgan, what is gained is microseconds.  Take the `+` generic.  If you do something like `1:100 + 1` it runs in less than one microsecond, but I can still dispatch (e.g. `as.Date("2013-01-01") + 1`) if desired.  The key is that the initial decision to handle the default case does not require any R calls and as such is 2-3x faster.  This is what I want: a fast default case, with the _possibility_ of slower dispatch if an object actually has a dispatchable class.

Comment: @MartinMorgan, see update to question for details of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not entirely satisfactory, but addresses part of my problem.  Basically, let's register a faux generic that actually checks for objectness before dispatch:

```
genericfun <- function(x) {
  if(is.object(x)) {
    UseMethod("genericfun")
  } else {
    #.Call(CFunNativeSymbol, x)
  }
}
genericfun.default <- function(x) {
  #.Call(CFunNativeSymbol, x)
}
obj <- structure(1:100, class="obj")
non.obj <- 1:100
microbenchmark(
  genericfun(non.obj),
  genericfun(obj),
  genericfun.default(non.obj)
)
```

Produces (note, this is clearly straining the precision of `microbenchmark` on my windows system):

```
Unit: nanoseconds
                        expr  min   lq median   uq   max neval
         genericfun(non.obj)  367  732  733.0 1098 16457   100
             genericfun(obj) 6217 6583 6583.0 6949 35838   100
 genericfun.default(non.obj)    0    1  183.5  366  1463   100
```

The generic dispatch is now down to under a microsecond.

Additionally, to the extent this is used recursively, the call to the R generic only need happen if the evaluation of `is.object` in C returns TRUE, so recursive structure containing only non-objects need not exit from C at any point.

There are probably many issues with this approach (not the least is the horrendous-hack nature of it) that will become apparent with use, but this is the best I can come up with for now.  One issue that comes to mind right away is that dispatch on implicit classes will not happen (e.g. `is.object(matrix()) == FALSE`).